# What are good public datasets for time series analysis with "certified" (by papers in the literature) good predictors of the target variable?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, model-evaluation, predictor

I have to test different models for time series forecasting and predictors (exogenous covariates) goodness evaluation and I would like to use datasets used in relevant scientific publications that have "certified" the goodness of some predictor variables (of the target variable), so I can compare the results and try to refine my models.